# Find div position in Mozilla firefox browser

Tags: jquery

I want to find the div position for some calculation. And I am trying the following scenarios it will works in Chrome browser

```
$('#menuFinder').offset().top;//First

document.getElementById('menuFinder').getBoundingClientRect();//Second

$("#menuFinder").position();//Third
```

But both these codes are not worked in Mozilla browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) in jquery :-

```
var position = $('#menuFinder').position(); //here position will be object having .left and .top properties.
```

**position.left and position.top** will have desired coordinates of a div.

[**Fiddle Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vcttomh1/)

**EDIT :-**

**Complete Code :-**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var position = $('#menuFinder').position(); 
  $('span').text("Left:" + position.left + "    Top:" + position.top);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menuFinder">Test</div>
<span></span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... But the code will not works in my scenario, i don't  why it happens. When i'm trying the same scenario in another file it works..

Comment: @user3406338...just check whether you have given jquery reference in your page properly or not and check for any console errors..

Answer (score 0):

Please check with following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  x=$("#menuFinder").position();
  alert("Top position: " + x.top + " Left position: " + x.left);
});
```

Comment: I have checked it for Mozilla Firefox as well, it works (Currently using Firefox Version 24.3.0)